# SAP BAPI for vendor creation and editing

Tags: edit, background-process, vendor, bapi, sap-r3

Has anyone ever created a BAPI to create or edit a vendor in *SAP R/3 4.6c* in the background? I found two BAPIs: **BAPI_VENDOR_CREATE** and **BAPI_VENDOR_EDIT**, but both only work online (they call transactions **XK01** and **XK02**).

Basically I need a way to call a function module that would do the same work as transactions **XK01** and **XK02** but don't need to be called online.

Looking on the SAP community forums, I found a lot of people with the same needs as me, but the answer was never complete.

Could someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean when you write "both 2 works only with the UI"? BAPIs are designed for headless use.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @vwegert Both of those BAPIs just do a `CALL TRANSACTION` so cannot be used headless, unfortunately.

Comment: @mjturner I guess you learn something new every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, SAP doesn't provide BAPIs for vendor creation/change that can be called in the background (this is, unfortunately, still the case in newer releases).

You have a few possible options:

1. Create your own BAPI, using (unreleased) SAP function modules for the vendor update.
2. Create your own BAPI, creating/changing the vendor via a BDC session.

I'd go with option **2**. No, BDCs are *never* ideal and they have a lot of downsides but even a lot of SAP standard function modules for vendor creation seem to go that route and you'll at least be certain that the data in your system is consistent, unlike if you use something like function module `VENDOR_INSERT`, which does direct table updates without application validation.

Check if the standard vendor data transfer program (`RFBIKR00`) is in your system - it uses batch input so could be a very useful starting point for your BDC.

Comment: According to your experience, how much time do you think it would take to  create the BAPI via BCD?

Comment: @SilvanoBini It's difficult to say as I don't know what data you need to complete (e.g., is it finance or purchasing views or both, how have you configured the vendor master, etc), but it's not going to be a massive undertaking. It's certainly not more than a few days **at most**.